# Operation not permitted error when defining socket type in python-zmq

Tags: python, docker, zeromq

I get the following error ("Operation not permitted") when trying to define a socket type.

```py
root@44e95193982d:/# python3
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 13 2023, 12:18:29) [GCC 12.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zmq
>>> zmq.__version__
'24.0.1'
>>> context = zmq.Context()
>>> socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
Operation not permitted (src/thread.cpp:269)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Since I am running everything as `root` I should not get `Operation not permitted` errors.

The weird thing is that I am running this code inside a container and depending on the host machine it might or might not crash. Further, on the same problematic host machine a significantly older version of zmq (version 16.0.2) at another container works fine.

Since the error message is not very descriptive I do not even know how to start debugging this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there is an issue with the docker version used in the host, which is incompatible with python threads for some base images. Using `FROM debian:buster-slim` as a base image is a workaround.

I still do not know the root cause and a proper solution to this problem though.